# yii2 fileinput not working

Tags: file-io, yii2

I'm new in yii2.
On my project use `kartik\file\Fileinput;`

In local its good working and when upload to my host get this error:

in the first of my file this :

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use kartik\file\FileInput;
```

PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException

> Class 'kartik\file\FileInput' not found
>   1. in /home/user/domains/myhost.com/public_html/modules/admin/views/photos/_form.php
>   at line 27 18192021222324252627282930313233343536

```
echo $form->field($model, 'filename[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `use kartik\widgets\FileInput;` instead of `use kartik\file\FileInput;`

Comment: I think I did not include this module files on the host